# Installing rmagick gem fails on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

On MAC OS X LION while install rmagic gem, I am getting desperately this error:

```
    Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions 
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    checking for gcc... yes
    checking for Magick-config... yes
    checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
    checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
    checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
    /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
        from /Users/joel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/joel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
    An error occured while installing rmagick (2.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Used this installer to install ImageMagick before hand

http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/ 
picked ImageMagick 6.7.3-2 for Mac OS X Lion

I spend a couple of hours on this, hope someone can give me a lead on how to resolve this.

ADDITIONAL ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find MagickWand.h.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what fixed it!

C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.7.7-6/include/ImageMagick gem install rmagick